# Magento 2 Import Export - Configurable Products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.2

Magento 2 provides import of configurable products features or not ? if it  provides, how should i import configurable products in magento 2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

Magento 2 provides utility to import configuarble product with it's associated product via CSV

Please refer following link.

http://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2016/01/magento-2-import-configurable-products/

https://community.magento.com/t5/Admin-Configuration-Questions/Import-configurable-products-in-Magento-2/td-p/27072

Answer (score 4):

Please check below link to get proper idea for import & export product in Magento 2

http://www.lexiconn.com/blog/2016/01/magento-2-import-configurable-products/

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample csv for configurable products import https://github.com/firebearstudio/magento2-import-export-sample-files/blob/master/Improved%20Import%20:%20Export%20-%20Sample%20Files/products_configurable_improved.csv

Complete guide to import of configurable product with examples - https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-configurable-products.html